# Rendering axis labels in 3D data plot using Graphics3d

Tags: graphics3d

I have a data and I'm trying to plot the data. But the plot axes label keeps on changing when rotating the figure for in order to find the right position of view point, then save it later.

I checked different answers but I guess to ignorant to figure out much.

Is there a way to force the labeling to a particular position
[image]

Here the axes labels I want to have, Y labeling in the bottom right plane (going inward) not on the the top right(going inward). Is there a way out?
Keeping others intact.

Is there a general way to put the labels where we want?

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1],
  Riffle[{Red, Blue},
   Point /@ Transpose[SortBy[Last] /@ Partition[dataToPlot3wg, 2]]]},
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {-\[Pi], \[Pi]},
 Ticks -> {{0, 1, 2}, {-1,0, 1}, {-\[Pi], 0, \[Pi]}},
 AxesLabel -> {Style["X", Large, Bold, Gray],
   Style["Y", Large, Bold, Gray],
   Style[Rotate["Z", 90 Degree], Large, Bold, Gray]} ,
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, FontSize -> 30]]
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use the [`AxesEdge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesEdge) option.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks! I used it `AxesEdge -> {{Automatic, None, None}, {None, None, None}, {Automatic, 
   None, Automatic}}`. But it's not giving me the right position. I'm missing something?

Comment: L.K, try `AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}` and play with combinations of 1s and -1s to place the each axes on the desired edge.

Comment: @kglr Problem is solved thanks a lot to both of you. Is there a way to put the text properly, so that it won't overlap? Sorry for many ques. This is the [figure now](https://imgur.com/a/O4mrar1)